# How to convert address(input) to coordinates using Tom Tom in Laravel 9 and save them in db?

Tags: laravel, api, geocoding, tomtom

We are struggling to try to convert an address to coordinates using TomTom (their documentation sucks fr) in Laravel 9. At this point, we need a proper guide; we don't know how to begin.

**Model**

```
use GuzzleHttp\Client;

public static function getCoordinatesFromAddress(string $address): array
{
    $client = new Client();
    $response = $client
        ->get('https://api.tomtom.com/search/2/geocode/%27.urlencode($address).%27.json', [
        'query' => [
            'key' => 'my_tomtom_api_key',
            'limit' => 1
        ]
    ]);

    $data = json_decode($response->getBody(), true);
    $latitude = $data['results'][0]['position']['lat'];
    $longitude = $data['results'][0]['position']['lon'];

    return compact('latitude', 'longitude');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i just tried with the below code and it worked.
Please note i used (hardcoded) the address they suggest at the beginning in the geocoding documentation.

```
    $client = new Client();
    $address = urlencode('109 Park Row, New York, United States');
    $response = $client->get('https://api.tomtom.com/search/2/geocode/%27.'.$address.'.%27.json', [
        'query' => [
            'key' => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
            'limit' => 1
        ]
    ]);
    error_log(print_r($response,true));
    $data = json_decode($response->getBody(), true);
    $latitude = $data['results'][0]['position']['lat'];
    $longitude = $data['results'][0]['position']['lon'];
    return compact('latitude', 'longitude');
```